# get the photo URL of the user with (Apple sign in)

Tags: objective-c, swift, apple-sign-in

I implemented google sign in and stored information about each user (name, email, photoURL).

now I want to implement the same with apple sign in, so far everything works but I don't know how I can get the photo URL, does apple even provide that?

these are the Scopes that I request from the user:

```
['email', 'full_name',]
```

what is the scope name for the photo URL?

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

apple's sign-in doesnt provide a picture